# SOAP Service AND JSF/Icefaces in a single Application

Tags: c#, java, web-services, jsf, soap

I've got a JSF/Icefaces Webapplication (mainly a website where you can buy stuff)
and I have a Desktopapplication written in C# (where you can use the bought stuff)

But my DesktApp needs to acces the Server via SOAP Services (to retrieve the bought elements)

What would be best practice - SOAP and JSF in one APP, or 2 seperate Applications?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how would you really benefit from a new application (i.e. new domain or context)?

I have a similar situation where I use JSF for Web Front and Servlet for web service requests and it works absolutely fine.

If you are using EJB3.0 then you can simply create web services by `@WebService` annotation on State Beans.